# get the results of both queries in one query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two queries

QUERY 1

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as m1 , bank
from test t1
group by bank
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT SUM(amount21) as m , bank
from test2 t1
group by bank
```

How to get the results of both queries in one query ?

```
m | m1 | bank
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
select q1.m1, q2.m, coalesce(q1.bank, q2.bank)
from
(
    SELECT SUM(amount) as m1 , bank
    from test t1
    group by bank
) q1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(amount21) as m , bank
    from test2 t1
    group by bank
) q2 on q1.bank = q2.bank
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill in what you need:

```
SELECT x.a, y.b 
FROM (SELECT * from a) as x, (SELECT * FROM b) as y
GROUP BY bank
```

Comment: No JOIN condition?

Comment: All down to personal preference.